# if statement argument length 0

Tags: r, if-statement, arguments, zero

Hopefully a simple question:

I am getting an "argument is of length zero" for the if statement line:

```
for (i in 1:(length(MixedDF))) {
      if (MixedDF[i,1] - MixedDF[i-1,1] == 1) {
      SwitchInd[i] = MixedDF$trial[i]
  }
}
```

Where MixedDF is a large matrix and SwitchInd is a matrix of zeroes that is supposed to get filled in with the indices identified in the if statement. `MixedDF$trial` or `MixedDF[i,1]` is the first column in the matrix. This column contains integers starting at 51 and going to 74, where there are many rows with the same value. So for example `MixedDF$trial <- c(51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53.....)`. I want to identify the indices where the trial changes, so 51 to 52, 52 to 53 and so on. More generally I want to understand why the if statement isn't working, it seems straightforward.

Comment: When `i` is `1`, `MixedDF[i-1,1]` is not well formed.

Comment: A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) would be nice. This makes it a lot easier for others to help you.

Comment: using which I get an "argument to 'which' is not logical. I had set MixedDF$trial to as.numeric, not sure if that matters.

Comment: Yes Ronak, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: numeric. However, this does work: which(MixedDF$trial[-1] != MixedDF$trial[-length(MixedDF$trial)])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives the indices where the value changes

```
x <- c(51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53)
which(diff(x)!= 0) + 1 

#[1]  6 15
```

Comment: Thanks this works when class is appropriate and is simple; also found this to work: which(MixedDF$trial[-1] != MixedDF$trial[-length(MixedDF$trial)]) but could not get the for loop to work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have NULL values.  Also, you are not defining the cases where the if statement fails.  Add an 'else' condition.

```
if (MixedDF[i,1] - MixedDF[i-1,1] == 1) 
{
    SwitchInd[i] = MixedDF$trial[i]
}
else
{
    SwitchInd[i] = SOME VALUE
}
```

Another problem is you can't start from 1 (when i is 1, i-1 is 0).

Comment: Yes got that from nrussel, I just changed the for to go from 2:length(DF).